# how to hide bottomnavigation and app bar on scroll when app bar inside FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, scroll, bottomnavigationview, appbar, container-view

I know we can hide bottomnavigation and app bar on scroll when both are the direct children of coordinate layout, But my issue is different, I have one home fragment and bottom view is a part of this fragment with FragmentContainerView, now my app bar inside the fragment which i am setting in container view, when i am scrolling, app bar getting scroll properly but i am not sure how to scroll bottom navigation as well,

home_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/rootFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_bar_tab_color"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/navText"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/navText"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_bar_tab_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

another fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvProgressBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/rvProgressBar"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/twentyfour_24dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/eighteen_18dp"
                android:text="@string/t2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                style="@style/text_16px_franklin_gothic_normal_" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can some one please explain me, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` inside your BottomNavigationView? In my case, it works just fine :)

I also suggest you to use CoordinatorLayout instead of ConstraintLayout in your home_fragment.xml